# Getting last change of public link

Tags: node.js, dropbox, dropbox-api

How can i get the last change time stamp of a public linked file or folder, by using node.js? Without including it into "my dropbox".
In some dropbox modules i found only api calls, which allows retrieving this kind of meta data from files that i own, or getting those meta information while downloading the file, par example `get` from `node-dbox`

Harvesting this data from the shared link website seems only to work with a javascript evaluating system like phantom(.js) - what in my case would be extremely slow.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no API for shared links themselves, so there's currently no proper way to get information like this from a shared link.

Comment: @Greg: So are there only two ways to handle those links, the one i described above, or including them into a dropbox? Is the inclusion possible via api call?